# ApexCharts - When animation is enabled, full graph doesn't print

Tags: apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts version 3.19.3 but right now, I have included only one js in my HTML files. It's **apexcharts.min.js** (CDN)

The graphs are working great. But, when I print them, entire chart is not printed.
I have used following code to print graph.

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">

function fnPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('printContent');
    var gr = document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML;
        var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
        if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
        oDoc.write("<html><head><title>Bar Graph</title>");
        oDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
        oDoc.write("<center><br /><br />" + gr + "</center></body></html>");        
        oDoc.close();       
    }
    catch(e){
        self.print();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="printContent" name="printContent" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<div id="imgDiv" style="display:none;"><img id="imgElem"></img></div>

<div id="chart"></div>
<a href="javascript:fnPrint();">Print Graph</a>

</body>
```

Animations option is on like following,

```
var options = {
    animations:{
        enabled: true,
    }
},
```

Following lines are added after **chart.render();** line

```
var dataURL = chart.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
  console.log(imgURI)
  document.getElementById("imgElem").setAttribute('src', imgURI);
})
```

As seen above, I logged imgURI value.
Observation is, total size of imgURI string goes down when animation is enabled. e.g. size of imgURI in bar graph with animation is 28KB. Without animation, it's 34KB.

I have uploaded log files which show value of imgURI, please check.

[Bar graph with animation disabled](https://textuploader.com/1ge45)

[Bar graph with animation enabled](https://textuploader.com/1ge4d)

Note : I can't post more than 8 links so I have included code for only bar graph above.

Please see screeshots below.
This is how printed documents look like.

[Bar graph with animation disabled](https://prnt.sc/tkixla)

[Bar graph with animation enabled](https://prnt.sc/tkiy23)

[Line graph with animation disabled](https://prnt.sc/tkiyjj)

[Line graph with animation enabled](https://prnt.sc/tkiyof)

[Multi Bar graph with animation disabled](https://prnt.sc/tkiyyb)

[Multi Bar graph with animation enabled](https://prnt.sc/tkiz4x)

Please advise.

Thanks
Sandeep

**Further update : 1 August 2020**

Hello,

Further update on this issue.
I have modified the code. The graphs are printing now.

Close but no cigar !!

Earlier, the code was like following

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">

function fnPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('printContent');
    var gr = document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML;
        var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
        if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
        oDoc.write("<html><head><title>Bar Graph</title>");
        oDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
        oDoc.write("<center><br /><br />" + gr + "</center></body></html>");        
        oDoc.close();       
    }
    catch(e){
        self.print();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="printContent" name="printContent" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<div id="imgDiv" style="display:none;"><img id="imgElem"></img></div>

<div id="chart"></div>
<a href="javascript:fnPrint();">Print Graph</a>

</body>
```

I modified it to following

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">

function fnPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('printContent');
    var gr = document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML;
    var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
    if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
    oDoc.write("<html><head><title></title>");
    oDoc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /></head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
    oDoc.write("<center><br /><br />" + gr + "</center>");
    oDoc.write("</body></html>");
    oDoc.close();
    }
    catch(e){
        self.print();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="printContent" name="printContent" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<div id="chart"></div>
<a href="javascript:fnPrint();">Print Graph</a>

</body>
```

Please check **Bar printing but problems** link in comments section.

So, I used console.log to trace HTML.
I added following line in code and graphs print fine.

`gr = gr.substring(0,gr.indexOf('<div class="apexcharts-legend">'));`

So, final code looks like following.

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">

function fnPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('printContent');
    var gr = document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML;
    gr = gr.substring(0,gr.indexOf('<div class="apexcharts-legend">'));
    var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
    if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
    oDoc.write("<html><head><title></title>");
    oDoc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /></head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
    oDoc.write("<center><br /><br />" + gr + "</center>");
    oDoc.write("</body></html>");
    oDoc.close();
    }
    catch(e){
        self.print();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="printContent" name="printContent" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<div id="chart"></div>
<a href="javascript:fnPrint();">Print Graph</a>

</body>
```

I had to make change according to graph type. Above fix worked for bar and line graphs.
But, for multiple bar graph, I had to modify that line like following.

`gr = gr.substring(0,gr.indexOf('<div class="apexcharts-tooltip apexcharts-theme-light"'));`

Line graphs print fine. But, bar graphs are not perfect.
Please see screenshots in comment area.

Note : I can't post more than 8 links. So, I have put them in comments.

You'll also observe that small colour icons next to legend are absent. I thought, I trimmed the output HTML, so they disappeared. But, on printing entire HTML, result is same.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Sandeep

**Further update : 8 August 2020**

Hello,

Further update.
If I disable zoom, move icons (seen at top right corner), graph prints fine. I commented following line.

```
xaxis:{
    //tickPlacement: 'on',
}
```

I can't post more than 8 links. So, please check those in comment area.

However, the print is always not perfect.
Please advise.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: **Reference links for my updates on 1 August 2020**

[Bar printing but problems](https://prnt.sc/to8lvr) ********************* 

[Single bar graph](https://prnt.sc/to8mma) ****************************

[Multiple bar graph](https://prnt.sc/to8mry) ************************

[Multiple bar graph 1](https://prnt.sc/to8mwv) ***********************

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: **Reference links for my updates on 8 August 2020** [Bar graph print with zoom, move icons](https://prnt.sc/to8mma) *********************** [Bar graph print without zoom, move icons](https://prnt.sc/ts48hf)

Comment: Hello,

Does anyone have answer?

Thanks,
Sandeep